# Checking if an event is not null before firing it in C#

Tags: c#

I often see this for custom events:

```
void InvokeCustomEvent(EventArgs e)
{
    var handler = CustomEvent;
    if (handler != null) handler(this, e);
}
```

But is creating the handler variable required, best practice, or superfluous, when compared to:

```
void InvokeCustomEvent(EventArgs e)
{
    if (CustomEvent != null) CustomEvent(this, e);
}
```

?

Comment: IMO, it should be moved to StackOverflow, though I believe this question is already present there.

Comment: @Snowbear: Yep, there's [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/672638/use-of-null-check-in-event-handler). I should have checked...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> But is creating the handler variable required, best practice, or superfluous, when compared to:

Yes, it is needed. Otherwise, `CustomEvent` could be set to `null` after you've checked for `null`, but before you've invoked it. This can happen if it gets set in another thread, or if one of the event handlers unregisters itself or another one.

I usually have this declared somewhere in my codebase:

```
public static class EventExtensions
{
    public static void Raise<T>(this EventHandler<T> handler, T args) {
        if (handler != null) handler(args);
    }
}
```

Now, with any event handler, you can just do:

```
handler.Raise(args);
```

You can call an extension method with a `null` this, so it will do the right thing even if `handler` is `null`. Furthermore, by copying `handler` into the local variable used by `Raise`, you automatically get the copy you need to make sure the handler won't disappear under you. Works like a charm.

Comment: Too bad the inventers of C# didn't simply make that the default behavior for invoking an event.  Mind boggling to me that they didn't, since invoking an event with no subscribers should be a perfectly legitimate "do nothing" operation.

Comment: There is no concept of "an event with no subscribers". When you create an object that has some `event` fields, they will be `null` to begin with. When you register the first handler with `myObj.SomeEvent += SomeHandler`, that `+=` is creating a new EventHandler object from scratch. This way an object doesn't pay a price for instantiating empty EventHandlers on creation if it never uses them. Does make them a bit uglier to use though. :(

Comment: My initial (and maybe a bit naive) belief was pretty much like what @supercat wants, that the event at least registered "transparently" a base, "do nothing" operation.

Comment: @MPelletier: That might be nice, but that means you'd have to create the EventHandler to begin with. Imagine you have a class with fifty events on it. When you instantiate that class, it won't waste any time touching them. They'll just all be `null` fields. The first time you register a handler on one of them using `+=`, it will get created. That way you don't pay the price of constructing a bunch of unused `EventHandlers` every time you create an object. What you propose might be a better idea, but you'd lose that performance advantage.

Comment: Seems I can't call this extension method on more specific kinds of `EventHandler<T>` like `PropertyChangedEventHandler`.  This makes it not so useful I think.

Answer (score 8):

You actually don't need the null check at all if you use the following trick.  Simply create a default, empty handler that is always registered, so the event is guaranteed to never be null.

Declare your event like so (notice the `= delegate { }` bit)

```
public event EventHandler CustomEvent = delegate { };
```

And you can then invoke it without any null checks.

Comment: I like this answer (and choosing was truly heart-breaking) for its simplicity. I'd rather do this in cases of a very light structure, and not, as suggested above, dozens of events in many instances of the same class.